# Can I use two includes method inside a filter function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Can I use two includes method inside a filter function in Javascript?

I want a new array without these statuses ('active', 'refunded'). How can I achieve that? I was thinking of using two includes methods but it seems not to work.

```
const availableModules = [
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#305b2d",
    status: "active",
    modules: 
    [
    { key: "tshirt",
    color: "#066da0",
    status: "active step 2"}, 
    {  key: "tshirt",
    color: "#772016",
    status: "active step 3"}
    ],
  },
  {
    key: "tshirt",
    color: "#742016",
    status: "canceled",
  },
  {
    key: "hat",
    color: "#201010",
    status: "refunded",
  },
 {
    key: "short",
    color: "#702213",
    status: "delivered",
  },
 {
    key: "short",
    color: "#702010",
    status: "Pending",
  },
 {
    key: "shirt",
    color: "#702411",
    status: "Closed",
  },
];


const seeOther = availableModules.filter(m=> console.log(!m.status.includes('active', 'refunded')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like this

```
availableModules.filter(x => ((x.status !== "active") && (x.status !== "refunded")))
```

Comment: Sweet!, Thank you @Abu

Comment: absolutely!@Abu